# How to make python selenium click function without error?

Tags: python, selenium

It's Python Selenium, but the image doesn't click and I get an error where I need to click the image.
The coding went like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBPm3.png)

The error comes like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPlRQ.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code and error messages. Please edit your question and paste in the code and error(s) as text with appropriate formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `[0]`  for `find_element` ?

Note that `find_element` returns a single web element, whereas `find_elements` return a list in Selenium-Python.

so you have two options :

1. Use `find_elements`

   ```
   driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('some css here')[0].click()
   ```

or

2. Use `find_element` like this  :

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('some css here').click()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Line 9: `find_element_by_css_selector(...)[0]`

Find element (singular) does not return and array. You cannot use the `[0]` at the end.

Selenium has `find_element_xxx` (singular) and `find_elements_xxx` (multiple).

The singular form returns a single element.
The multiple form returns a iteratable object.

You're using the former, so no array to choose a position from